# Intuition behind these statements being equivalent

Tags: logic, intuition

I have encountered a strange equivalence, and I am trying to make intuitive sense of it, which I have been able to do in many similar cases. Here it is:

$$[(p\Rightarrow q)\Rightarrow r] \Longleftrightarrow[((\sim p)\Rightarrow r)\wedge(q\Rightarrow r)]$$

What I'm really looking for is a set of statements in English, for which I will understand that the statements on either side of the biconditional really do say the same thing. What I invented for the statement on the left is this, a description of an electric fence:

$p=$ "I touch the wire"

$q=$ "I get shocked"

$r=$ "There is current in the wire"

Thus: "If my touching the wire is sufficient for my getting shocked, then there is current in the wire." I believe this statement is represented by the expression "$(p\Rightarrow q)\Rightarrow r$".

However, when I try to plug these statements into the expression on the right, I get apparent nonsense: "If I don't touch the wire, then there is current in the wire, and also, if I get shocked, then there is current in the wire." In particular, the first half of this conjunction seems bizarre...

Despite this seeming lack of accord, the truth tables for the two statements show that they are equivalent. In both cases, they are only false in three cases: when the truth values of $(p,q,r)$ are $(T,T,F)$, $(F,T,F)$ or $(F,F,F)$. In all other cases, both statements are true.

Can anyone help me reconcile this strange situation? Is this just the strangeness of material implication rearing its counter-intuitive head, again? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To me, it seems like your example on the left is $(p \wedge q) \Rightarrow r$.

Comment: Can you think of an example that works better?

Comment: No.  I think the problem is that none of those implications will be true with all premises true at the same time, which is the only time $\Rightarrow$ makes "natural sense."  So, you'll always have a case where you get a $F \Rightarrow T$ which is hard to make common-sense out of.

Comment: Hmm... my usual way to make sense of that is, “if you climb the mountain, I’ll give you $100.” Then, if you don’t climb the mountain, I wasn’t lying. This one however... is more complicated...

Comment: If we convert $p\implies q$ to $\neg p\lor q$ then the left side says "if I don't touch the wire or I get a shock then there is current in the wire". With that in mind it seems clear that your example does say that not touching the wire implies that there is current in the wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a nice path from the LHS statement to the RHS statement, and this helps me troubleshoot my example:

$$(p\Rightarrow q)\Rightarrow r \\
(\sim p \vee q)\Rightarrow r\\
\sim(p\,\wedge\sim q)\Rightarrow r\\
(p\,\wedge\sim q)\vee r\\
(p\vee r)\,\wedge(\sim q\vee r)\\
(\sim p\Rightarrow r)\wedge(q\Rightarrow r)$$

This is not the shortest possible path between the statements, but I like that it provides a variety of rephrasings, each close to its neighbors, which make it easy to test example sentences for goodness-of-fit. My electric fence example shows its weakness right away after the first step. The real logical relation there is the other way around:

$$r\Rightarrow(p\Rightarrow q)$$

The current being on is sufficient for the implication: if I touch, I get shocked. The implication "if I touch I get shocked" is *necessary* for saying the current is on. My mistake was confusing sufficiency and necessity in that situation.

As for a good example for the original statement, based on the answer by @Bertrand Wittgenstein's Ghost, we have:

$p=$ "It rains"

$q=$ "I have an umbrella"

$r=$ "I stay dry"

$p\Rightarrow q=$ "Whenever it rains, I have an umbrella"

Thus:

"If, whenever it rains I have an umbrella, then I stay dry"

and

"If it doesn't rain, then I stay dry; also, if I have an umbrella, then I stay dry."

Answer (score 2):

$(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow R)\iff((\lnot P\rightarrow R)\land (Q\rightarrow R ))$

So you set up the propositions like this:

$P:$ I touch the wire

$Q:$ I get shocked

$R:$ There is current in the wire

That would make the left hand side:

If (if i touch the wire, then i get shocked), then there is current in the wire.

Which is the same as: if i touch the wire and then get shocked implies there is current in the wire.

Right hand side would be:

If I don't touch the wire, then there is current in wire **and** if I get shocked, then there is current in the wire.

Well, think of it like this:

$P:$ Its Raining

$Q:$ I have an umbrella

$R:$ I don't get wet

L.H.S:

If it's raining, and I have an umbrella, then I don't get wet.

R.H.S

If its not raining, then I don't get wet **and** if I have an umbrella, then I don't get wet.

Both of these statements make intuitive sense. In fact, your initial example makes sense too, however in terms of truth-tables, but if you translate it into colloquial english it is not easy to see because the statement: "If i touch the wire, then I get shocked" assumes there is current in the wire. Keeping this assumption in mind we get: "if I don't touch the wire, then there is current in the wire" obviously, because we assumed there is current in the wire. Similarly, "If i get shocked, then there is current in the wire", obviously because that is our assumption.

See: $(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r$ is equivalent to $(\lnot p\lor q)\rightarrow r$

This equivalence shows that $r$ is actually embedded in $(p\rightarrow q)$. That is, if we suppose the $(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r$, then we suppose $r$ is is necessarily true.

**Aside:**

Deduction does not tell us anything *new*. In fact, it just explicates what other things we implicitly believe given an initial set of beliefs.

**hint:** 
Always try to keep your propositions simple.

Comment: I don't understand the English statement "If P then Q then R". If someone says to me, "If its raining, then I have an umbrella, then I don't get wet," I just wonder if they understand how language works.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Well, sentential logic is a crude approximation of normal, day-to-day language. That is, it will obviously sound choppy, or even wordy at times, but for what it is it gets the job done. Keep in mind, the aim in sentential logic is to see what we already believe given a set of beliefs. For example, if its raining, then i have an umbrella. This conditional in s.l. is stating that it is never the case that its raining and I don't have an umbrella. You might wonder, how is it possible for me to have an umbrella everytime it rains, what if i forget for instance.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs That implies, sentential logic is, in a sense, ideal approximation of language which will give you necessary connections. That is the aim.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my objection. You're trying to write "If (if p then q), then r" by writing "If p then q then r". That's incoherent. The clause "if p then q" can be rephrased in various ways, such as "p is sufficient for q" or "q is necessary for p", or "p only if q". Thus, an accurate phrasing of "if (if p then q), then r" is: "if p is sufficient for q, then r".

I certainly would not wonder how it is possible for you to have an umbrella every time it rains, because I understand the difference between an example sentence and reality.

Comment: Your example does seem to work, though, if we phrase it this way: If, whenever it rains you have an umbrella, then you stay dry." Equivalently, "If it doesn't rain then you stay dry, and also, if you have an umbrella, then you stay dry." This is satisfying.